# How to display json array response in html page

Tags: php, search, mobile, windows-mobile, arrays

I have a database where user can search database from html page. I can get the response for search keyword but it is displayed with echo php encode in php file where db connection is configured. I want to pass the JSON array response to my search html page.

Any Ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you separating php and html page?

Comment: Because php file is in server and I am developing this for mobile app

Comment: Then ask the question clearly and in the tag of that mobile platform

Comment: What's wrong with "echo php encode"?

Comment: If I echo it will display output with php file...I want that to display in html page without php